# Alternative to Microsoft XNA Game Studio?

Tags: c#, xna

For some reason the XNA Game Studio doesn't work on my PC. :( . It says something about pixel shaders and my hardware doesn't support something or the other. I just need to make some decent 2D games and demos. Neither do I think it will work on the PCs of my intended audience ( people from developing south-asian countries).

So is there any alternative for XNA that gives me equal performance and has a mature enough API?

Comment: Maybe [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/)?

Comment: Perhaps you could be specific about the errors you see?  Other game development systems may also require certain features, such as pixel shaders.  A graphics card less than 10 years old might be useful if you're serious about game development :)

Comment: XNA Game Studio should work on any modern PC, even if you don't have a fancy graphics card (which would be masked by the fact that XNA uses DirectX). Make sure you have the latest version of DirectX and make sure that it is configured correctly, and you'll be fine. Besides that argument, there's no better game library that I know of on Windows than XNA Game Studio...

Comment: Be sure to try and set the game to the "**Reach**" profile in project properties too.

Comment: @EddieEdwards yeah. I could get one. but the people I'm targeting are all from India, Pakistan and Bangladesh. Developing countries where the Pentium 4 is still considered _high tech_. Therefore, I'm asking for some library that supports graphic cards > 10 years old.

Comment: You need to change your projects properties to Reach and XNA Game Studio should work. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/07/19/selecting-reach-vs-hidef.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) (a game programming library)

Edit to provide more information:

> Allegro 4 and Allegro 5 are cross-platform, libraries mainly aimed at video game and multimedia programming. They handle common, low-level tasks such as creating windows, accepting user input, loading data, drawing images, playing sounds, etc. and generally abstracting away the underlying platform. However, Allegro is not a game engine: you are free to design and structure your program as you like.

Allegro 4 and 5 support the major OSs (Unix/Linux, Windows (MSVC, MinGW) and MacOS X).  The engine supports 2D graphics primitives natively (you will need a separate API, like OpenGL or DirectX for 3D rendering, but you said that is not your target).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out ANX:

> The ANX.Framework is a framework which is source compatible with Microsoft's XNA framework 4.0. Source compatibility means, that you can "translate" a XNA game project to be a ANX game project by simply replacing all namespaces from Microsoft.XNA.Framework to ANX.Framework. The advantage of ANX is simply that you are able to swap the RenderSystem, the InputSystem and the AudioSystem. By swapping this systems you are no more limited to run your game using DirectX9 which XNA is using. ANX comes with a DirectX10 RenderSystem as a default. A DirectX 11, DirectX 11.1 and a OpenGL 3 RenderSystem is currently in development. This will make it possible to run your games on Linux and other plattforms which are supported by OpenGL etc. simply by swapping the namespaces.
>
> ~ Codeplex site: http://anxframework.codeplex.com/

It is still under heavy development but most of the basic XNA features are implemented.