# XNA alternative

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, .net-4.5

I recently switched to VS2012, managed to get XNA4 project working, but then I was wondering if VS2012 no longer supports (so really) and XNA seems to be such abandoned stuff, if there is an alternative to use, that is like:

- vs2012 compatible, and net4.5, c#
- not too high level (or well written and optimized)
- easy to learn after XNA
- free

Priorities are from above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978577/alternative-to-microsoft-xna-game-studio

Comment: I saw that, thank you. Shows only C++ projects, I am not interested in really.

Comment: Look at ANX again... it's not C++.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. It is pretty late for me it seems. Will give it a try too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271138/best-3d-graphics-engine-for-net

Or are you looking for a full game engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I heard good things about [Monogame](http://www.monogame.net/) and [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/). But Monogame is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You could look into monogame

http://www.monogame.net/

It's based on Mono so it's easier to port across from Desktop/Windows Phone like XNA would allow to also compile for Android and iOS (you need to buy a licence for those as they use Monodroid and monotouch components which aren't free)