# Display 3D model in .net

Tags: c#, .net, 3d

I need to display a simple 3D model in a c# .net app. Previously this would be done with XNA, but that's over with. What's the easiest way to do this now?

Comment: There were few topics like yours:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592861/xna-alternative

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714091/c-sharp-game-development-after-xna

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978577/alternative-to-microsoft-xna-game-studio

Comment: This is not a bad question per se, if you gave us more details. Do you want a fullscreen app? Windowed app? Winforms/WPF? What's the use case?

Comment: You might want to look into OpenTK which has last been updated on July 21st 2015. It's a OpenGL wrapper (plus OpenAL and Input handling) can be embedded into windowed apps too (as a control).